# CakePHP 3 Security component and Form Fields using VueJS

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, vue.js, cakephp-3.0

I'm creating an application using Vue.js and CakePHP 3.6.

When POST, security component throws a 400 error because the **_Token** fields are missing. I don't have problems with CSRF token, just form security validation.

I don't wanna disable the component in the whole application.

I found a non-solution: Expose _buildFieldToken from the Cake\View\Helper\SecureFieldTokenTrait but I think this will avoid the SecurityComponent purpose.

Any help are really welcome and appriciated.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers when you show some code so that people can properly comprehend your problem. _Where_ and _how_ do you build the forms? How is exposing `_buildFieldToken()` solving the problem? And do you actually _need_ to use form tampering protection for these problematic forms?

Answer (score 0):

The action in the controller (example: ajaxRequest) that you need access by fetch or axios, could be unlocked, in the controller:

if you have generated the form with the cake helpers, the _CSRFTOKEN is in the form label or hidden input (sorry inspect the Form element in the browser), when you have localized the token, add this in the data of .$post().

[ajax request cakephp](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests)

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
     //this line is not necessary if you pass the _csrfToken
     $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
     $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['ajaxRequest']);
}
```